# How to query CosmosDB for nested object value

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How can I retrieve objects which match `order_id = 9234029m`, given this document in CosmosDB:

```
{
    "order": {
        "order_id": "9234029m",
        "order_name": "name",
    }
}
```

I have tried to query in CosmosDB Data Explorer, but it's not possible to simply query the nested `order_id` object like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.order.order_id = "9234029m"
```

(Err: "Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'order'")

This seems like it should be so simple, yet it's not! (In CosmosDB Data Explorer, all queries need to start with `SELECT * FROM c`, but REST SQL is an alternative as well.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you discovered, `order` is a reserved keyword, which was tripping up the query parsing. However, you can get past that, and still query your data, with slightly different syntax (bracket notation):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE c["order"].order_id = "9234029m"
```

Answer (score 1):

This was due, apparently, to `order` being a reserved keyword in CosmosDB SQL, even if used as above.